# Is there a way to stop the box from knocking out a box-shadow?

Tags: css

Even with a transparent background, typically a `box-shadow` doesn't fill the contents of a box.

I think I have seen a demo where this wasn’t the case, but can’t recall how it was done. Does anyone know more about this?

Comment: I can only think of making the box's background the same color and alpha as the box shadow...

Comment: If the box is transparent, how can it cast a shadow? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having decent success simulating this by setting two box-shadows: one traditional box shadow, and the second `inset` with a very large spread value.

The suggestion to set the box’s background is also a good one, if you can match it up well.